# Como remover caracteres não alfanuméricos sem perder acentuação?

Tags: php, string, acentuação

Estou conseguindo remover os não alfanuméricos da seguinte forma `preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', null, $string );`

Porem, desta forma estou perdendo a acentuação das palavras, alguém tem alguma resposta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei bem o que está a tentar filtrar mas procurando dígitos e letras deve funcionar bem:

`[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]` quer dizer tudo o que não fôr:

- `\p{L}` - letras
- `\p{N}` - dígitos
- `\s` - espaco em branco

Pode usar assim:

```
$string = 'Olá amanhã é dia! #20%';
$limpa = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/', '', $string );
echo $limpa;
```

O resultádo é:

```
Olá amanhã é dia 20
```

Comment: Referência: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: Ajudou cara :) valeu

Comment: Não conhecia esse \P